Nextflow: channel.fromFilePairs() Map Post Processing
I have a question about channel.fromFilePairs() . I have the following nextflow script:
params.reads = "/path/to/my_reads/sample03_L001_R{1,2}_001.fastq.gz"

my_reads_ch = channel.fromFilePairs(params.reads)

println "reads: $my_reads_ch"

The script prints [sample03_L001_R, [/path/to/my_reads/sample03_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz, /path/to/my_reads/sample03_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz]].
The desired output is [sample03, [/path/to/my_reads/sample03_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz, /path/to/my_reads/sample03_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz]].
How do I remove the "_L001_R"?
I've tried

channel.fromFilePairs(params.reads).map{it[0] - /_\w+/, it[1]}

That gives me an ERROR: Unknown method invocation 'negative' on Pattern type.
Any suggestions? Many thanks

You just need to use the tilde operator to first create a pattern object:
Channel
    .fromFilePairs( params.reads )
    .map { sample, reads -> tuple( sample - ~/_\w+$/, reads ) }
    .view()

A better way though would be to better define your initial glob pattern, and let the fromFilePairs operator strip off the suffix for you. For example:
params.reads = "/path/to/my_reads/*_L001_R{1,2}_001.fastq.gz"

Channel
    .fromFilePairs( params.reads )
    .view()

Results:
$ nextflow run main.nf 

 N E X T F L O W   ~  version 24.04.3

Launching `main.nf` [golden_wescoff] DSL2 - revision: f7979e483d

[sample01, [/path/to/my_reads/sample01_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz, /path/to/my_reads/sample01_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz]]
[sample03, [/path/to/my_reads/sample03_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz, /path/to/my_reads/sample03_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz]]
[sample02, [/path/to/my_reads/sample02_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz, /path/to/my_reads/sample02_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz]]


thanks! I would give a +1 but I need 2 more rep points. I appreciate it
